# Add upto a specific cell in Excel

Tags: excel, sum

I have a column A with binary state UP or DN and a corresponding column B with values. I want to add values in column be upto when the state in column A changes. Like, as long as colum A is UP keep adding when it is DN give me the sum and then start from the next UP and keep adding till reach the next DN and give me the sum again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this screenshot

[image]

C2 has the formula (copied down)

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B2,B2+C1)
```

D2 has this formula (copied down)

```
=IF(C2>C3,C2,"")
```

If you only want to show the group totals, hide column C.